# DOM manipulation - Center H1 element using javascript

Tags: javascript

How can I center my h1 using javascript?

h1 is `<h1>Instrument track Recommendations</h1>`, I tried below and it does not work.

```
var centeredH1 = document.getElementsByTagName("h1");
centeredH1.style.textAlign = "center";`
```

I know it would work with an ID using `document.getElementById("h1id");` if I had one but I don't have an ID to work with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getElementsByTagName` returns an array-like object. If you have only one element, it will return an array-like object with one element. You need to get the `[0]` indexed element in that object. But as you have mentioned, it will be better to work with `id` in this case, if you want to attach styles only to one element.

```js
var centeredH1 = document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0];
// -------------------------------------------------^^^
centeredH1.style.textAlign = "center";
```

```html
<h1>Test</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/p8kzpoos/)

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var h1s = document.getElementsByTagName("h1");
h1s[0].style.textAlign="center";
```

**HTML**

```
<h1>
THIS IS TO BE CENTERED
</h1>
```

You need to access first element from array returned by javascript `getElementsByTagName`